# JMeter - Unable to stop / shutdown

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a very simple test plan in JMeter. There is just one thread group with one get request. ( I created this to isolate an issue which I faced in another real world test plan)

I was trying to increase the load and analyse the result.

While reaching a point, say 5000 users, JMeter does not stop.

I was unable to manually stop or shutdown. While trying to do so, the following message is displayed. But there is no response after that even though I waited.

It says you can see the active number of threads in the upper right hand side, but I can see that there are no active threads.

If I go to task manager to end the task, the same pop up message is displayed in JMeter and hence I am not able to end the task.

Please can someone advise on why I am getting this message when I could not see active threads in JMeter UI.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're violating one of the most [important JMeter best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean): GUI mode is only for tests development and/or debugging

If you want to execute your load test with 5000 virtual users you should be [running JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/result.jtl
```

Once your test finishes you can open the `result.jtl` file with the [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice or [generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from it